# After Macbook migration Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, qtgui

dyld: Library not loaded: QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)

Can anyone help to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The library seems to be missing. Reinstall QTGui framework.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can install OpenCV but for QT I could not. Could you please list the instructions for OpenCV and QT installation? I may reinstall again to combine them together. I prefer to use QT5 if it possible if my previous work is on QT4?

Many thanks Volker.